# Removing the Options for a select list using jQuery is returning this error "unable to get property length of undefined or null reference"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use to have this java script which get a select list and remove its options:-

```
var selectobject = document.getElementById("OrderAssignToApprover_9002e96d-1276-4355-9a2a-0c565d8079db_$DropDownChoice");
for (var i=selectobject.options.length-1; i>=0; i--)
    {

  selectobject.remove(i);//remove current usernames
    }
```

and it use to work well. now instead of selecting the element by its id (which is somehow long), I chose to select the element by using the start with, as follow:-

```
var selectobject = $('[id^="OrderAssignToApprover"]');    
for (var i=selectobject.options.length-1; i>=0; i--)
    {

  selectobject.remove(i);//remove current usernames
    }
```

but I start receiving these errors:-

on IE:-

```
unable to get property length of undefined or null reference
```

while on FireFox:-

```
exceptionTypeError: selectobject.options is undefined
```

so can anyone advice what is causing the errors, when I changed the selector from `document.getElementById()` to `$('[id^="OrderAssignToApprover"]')`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second case you must transform jquery object to js object:

```
var selectobject = $('[id^="OrderAssignToApprover"]');
selectobject.each(function(index,element){
    for (var i=element.options.length-1; i>=0; i--){
       element.remove(i);
    }
})
```

OR if your selector has only one element:

```
var selectobject = $('[id^="OrderAssignToApprover"]')[0];

for (var i=selectobject.options.length-1; i>=0; i--){
   selectobject.remove(i);
}
```

But to avoid other issue ... first check if your selectobject length if greater than zero with:

```
console.log($('[id^="OrderAssignToApprover"]').length)
```

Comment: `var selectobject = $('[id^="OrderAssignToApprover"]')[0];` worked well for me...

Comment: Ok. But take care if many id's begin with `OrderAssignToApprover` then only work for the first `selectobject`